# How to extract video frame GPS information in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, video, gps

I would like to extract GPS information from each frame of a video taken with a iPhone.

I use OpenCV 3 for Python. I can read the video and extract each frame but I don't know how to extract GPS information.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: That seems well out of scope of OpenCV. Perhaps some library that can extract metadata from Quicktime/MOV files, or video files in general.

Comment: I found the "exifread" and "hachoir" that may contain what I'm looking for. I will try them soon.

Comment: I tried exifread which works like a charm! I found my answers in this [post]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19804768/interpreting-gps-info-of-exif-data-from-photo-in-python)

Comment: @Yvanou how did you process the frame? that solution only gives how you can work with an image file.