# Extracting GPS info of a frame from a video (MP4) using Python

Tags: python, opencv, artificial-intelligence

I have recorded a video ( GPS activated) for one of my projects and at the same time some pics are captured I can able to get the info like latitude n longitude for images awa entire video from file properties. But I want to get the latitude n longitude values of each frame or at least few important frames in the video. I use Python 3.6 for programming purpose. There are suggestions to implement mmpython and ffmpeg but none worked. Any suggestions to kick-start this one?

Comment: Hope this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19804768/interpreting-gps-info-of-exif-data-from-photo-in-python) helps you out. It suggests using [exifread](https://pypi.org/project/ExifRead/).

Comment: Have seen but that is for images and we got that. I am asking for a frame in video.