# Can't get GPS coordinates from from EXIF data in python (Pillow or pyexiv2)

Tags: python, gps, python-imaging-library, exif, pyexiv2

I'm trying to extract GPS coordinates from a `JPG` image but I don't get much information with `pillow`.

This is my 1st attempt:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

my_img = Image.open("IMG_0547.jpg")

exif_data = my_img.getexif()
for tag_id in exif_data:
    tag = TAGS.get(tag_id, tag_id)
    data = exif_data.get(tag_id)

    print(f"{tag:16}: {data}")
```

Output:

```
TileWidth       : 512
TileLength      : 512
GPSInfo         : 1996
ResolutionUnit  : 2
ExifOffset      : 216
Make            : Apple
Model           : iPhone XS
Software        : 13.6
Orientation     : 1
DateTime        : 2020:08:13 21:01:41
XResolution     : 72.0
YResolution     : 72.0
```

Download the [image](https://github.com/alexmarginean16/emapped/blob/main/IMG_0547.jpg) from here

I also tried using `pyexiv2` but I get this error for only o line of code
`metadata = pyexiv2.ImageMetadata('IMG_0547.jpg')` which makes no sense because `ImageMetadata` is listed in the official documentation [here](https://python3-exiv2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#reading-and-writing-exif-tags)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "maps.py", line 17, in <module>
    metadata = pyexiv2.ImageMetadata('IMG_0547.jpg')
AttributeError: module 'pyexiv2' has no attribute 'ImageMetadata'
```

Can someone please help me get the coordinates?

Comment: I get a 404 when following the image download link.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I removed it by mistake. I was able to get a response from someone on reddit and they said the code worked on their computer so I figgured out there was a problem with my python installation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interpreting GPS info of exif data from photo in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19804768/interpreting-gps-info-of-exif-data-from-photo-in-python)   I can't get Pillow to work but `exifread` does.

Answer (score 5):

Pillow's Github has [an explanation](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/5863#issuecomment-984917141). The number in `GPSInfo` is merely a kind of offset (see https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/27724).

To find the content of `GPSInfo`, we can use `PIL.Image.Exif.get_ifd`:

```
from PIL import ExifTags, Image

GPSINFO_TAG = next(
    tag for tag, name in TAGS.items() if name == "GPSInfo"
)  # should be 34853

path = "my_geotagged_image.jpg"
image = Image.open(path)
info = image.getexif()

gpsinfo = info.get_ifd(GPSINFO_TAG)
```

Then proceed like here: [Interpreting GPS info of exif data from photo in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19804768/9778755)

Answer (score 0):

A little late but this is what I used recently to get image metadata.  I also modified it with **modify_iptc** and **modify_xmp** (not posted here).
[pyexiv2 Rev on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pyexiv2/)

```
import pyexiv2 

filename = r"C:\mydjifolder\Junk\DJI_0001.JPG"

img_meta = pyexiv2.Image(filename)

exif_dict = img_meta.read_exif()
xmp_dict = img_meta.read_xmp()
iptc_dict = img_meta.read_iptc()
print("\n**** IPTC Tags metadata ****")
for key, value in iptc_dict.items():
    print(f"TAG {key} = \t\t {value}")

print("**** EXIF Tags metadata ****")
for key, value in exif_dict.items():
    print(f"TAG {key} = \t\t {value}")


print("\n**** XMP Tags metadata ****")
for key, value in xmp_dict.items():
    if key == "Exif.Photo.MakerNote":
        continue
    print(f"TAG {key} = \t\t {value}")
    

print(xmp_dict["Xmp.xmp.CreateDate"])
print(iptc_dict["Iptc.Application2.DateCreated"])
img_meta.close
```